# Перебор всех строк таблицы

Tags: javascript

Есть некоторая таблица

```
<table id="aircasestable" border="0" bgcolor="#e0ecf8" width="218" cellpadding="0" cellspancing="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="70" align="center" style="font-size:11px;" bgcolor="#E3E3E3">Container No</td>
      <td width="130" align="center" style="font-size:11px;" bgcolor="#E3E3E3">Case No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="EFLH191022000002" value="CAXU9059282!EFLH191022000002!86110H0000">
      <td width="70" align="center" style="font-size:11px;">CAXU9059282</td>
      <td width="130" align="center" style="font-size:11px;">EFLH191022000002</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="EFLH191022000001" value="CAXU9059282!EFLH191022000001!86110H0000">
      <td width="70" align="center" style="font-size:11px;">CAXU9059282</td>
      <td width="130" align="center" style="font-size:11px;">EFLH191022000001</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Предположим, я хочу перебрать значения всех строк в цикле и сцепить их (для примера).

```
            var casetab = document.getElementById("aircasestable");
            document.frm.txthiddenworkedcase.value = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < casetab.length; i++) {
                document.frm.txthiddenworkedcase.value = document.frm.txthiddenworkedcase.value + "|" + casetab.rows[i].value;
            }
```

Но по итогу, input, в который я хочу положить их объединение остается пустым.

```
<input type="hidden" name="txthiddenworkedcase" id="Hidden3" value="">
```

Что не так в сцепляющем цикле? При этом, консоль не ругается на какие-либо ошибки.

Comment: При этом, обратил внимание, что casetab.length содержит undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const rStrings = [...document.querySelectorAll('tr[value]')]
  .map(tr => tr.getAttribute('value')); 
document.querySelector('input').value = rStrings.join('|');
```

```html
<table id="aircasestable" border="0" bgcolor="#e0ecf8" width="218" cellpadding="0" cellspancing="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="70" align="center" style="font-size:11px;" bgcolor="#E3E3E3">Container No</td>
      <td width="130" align="center" style="font-size:11px;" bgcolor="#E3E3E3">Case No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="EFLH191022000002" value="CAXU9059282!EFLH191022000002!86110H0000">
      <td width="70" align="center" style="font-size:11px;">CAXU9059282</td>
      <td width="130" align="center" style="font-size:11px;">EFLH191022000002</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="EFLH191022000001" value="CAXU9059282!EFLH191022000001!86110H0000">
      <td width="70" align="center" style="font-size:11px;">CAXU9059282</td>
      <td width="130" align="center" style="font-size:11px;">EFLH191022000001</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input readonly size="80">
```

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов, `...` это спред-оператор, он появился в языке с ES6. Принцип действия - раскладывает итерируемый объект на список элементов. Таким образом, заключив выражение с этим оператором в квадратные скобки, мы получаем преобразование в массив. В данном случае, это нужно для применения метода `map`.

Comment: `...` на MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Ну и `map` заодно: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("aircasestable").getElementsByTagName("TR")
```

- вероятно, вы хотели сделать это.
  Потому что ваш текущий код находит не строки, а таблицу, и соответственно, это 1 элемент, а не массив элементов.

Comment: Ну я хотел именно найти таблицу, на самом то деле, к строкам я пытался обращаться как `casetab.rows[i].value`. Но если сделать как говорите вы и обращаться через `casetab[i].value`, то цикл пробегает, но все `casetab[i].value` равны "undefined", хотя, очевидно, это не так и значение не пустое. При этом, `casetab[i].id` замечательно читаются и сцепляются.

Comment: При этом, обращение `document.getElementById("aircasestable")` вполне себе работает. Если вывести в input длинн, то всё показывает. То есть, `document.frm.txthiddenworkedcase.value = casetab.rows.length;` показывает верное количество строк в таблице. Но `casetab.rows[i].value` остается пустым

Comment: Ну, тогда нужно в условии перебора поставить i < casetab.rows.length .

Comment: А не работает, скорее всего, потому, что value - это нетипичный атрибут для tr. Попробуйте .getAttribute("value")

Comment: @Mik, дополни свой ответ пожалуйста (getAttribute), чтобы я мог удалить свой. Комментарий всего на 1 минуту не успел.

Comment: А, блин, поздно((

Comment: @yar85 Да ничего страшного)